# How do we take angles in the limits of integrals in Physics?

Tags: electric-fields, torque, dipole

I am looking at the following derivation of the potential energy of a dipole in a uniform electric field, paraphrased from [phys.libretexts.org](https://phys.libretexts.org):

> Consider an electric dipole $p$ placed in a uniform electric field
> $E$.  There is a torque on the dipole of magnitude  $p E \sinθ$ . In
> order to increase  $θ$ by $δθ$  you would have to do work amounting to
> $p E \sin{θ}\, δθ$. The amount of work you would have to do to
> increase the angle between  $p$ and $E$  from $0$ to $θ$ would be the
> integral of this from $0$ to $θ$, which is  $pE \,(1−\cosθ)$. This is
> the potential energy of the dipole, provided one takes the potential
> energy to be zero when  $p$ and $E$  are parallel. In many
> applications, writers find it convenient to take the potential energy
> (P.E.) to be zero when  $p$ and $E$  perpendicular. In that case, the
> potential energy is
>
> $$U= −p E \,\cosθ=−\textbf{p}⋅\textbf{E}.$$ This is negative when $θ$
> is acute and positive when $θ$ is obtuse. You should verify that the
> product of  $p$ and $E$ does have the dimensions of energy.

Now in this derivation, I do not understand from where the $\theta$ should be measured, because $\theta$ here is actually the angle between $p$ and $E$, so when the dipole move angles $d\theta$, angle between them should be obtuse and not acute, and so the derivation is done when $\theta$ is greater than $\frac{\pi}{2}.$ But it says the exact opposite. Could someone tell me what is happening?

Comment: Welcome to Physics StackExchange! In the future, please consider formatting the math and symbols in your question properly using LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

The angle $\theta$ is angle between $\textbf{p}$ and $\textbf{E}$. I think what you are asking is, "What orientation of the dipole should the initial angle, say $\theta_0$, correspond to?". If you integrate the differential of the work done in moving the dipole from an initial angle $\theta_0$ to a final angle $\theta$ w.r.t. $\textbf{E}$, you get the expression for the potential energy stored in the dipole on the right-hand-side. On the left-hand-side, you get the difference in energy, so $$U - U_0= -p E\, (\cos{\theta} - \cos{\theta_0}).$$  If you compare the terms in the expression above you will see that we can take $U_0 \equiv -pE \cos{\theta_0}.$ This is nothing but the $zero$ of the potential energy, which we can take to be anything (as long as we remain consistent). Typically, we take it to be 0 since it is the simplest choice, so this corresponds to assigning $\theta_0 = \frac{\pi}{2}.$

It is customary to measure angles positive in the counter-clockwise sense, so *if* you take $\theta_0 = \frac{\pi}{2}$ to be the zero of the potential energy, then this means the energy of the dipole is positive only when $\theta > \frac{\pi}{2}$.

On the other hand, you could define $U_0 \equiv -p\,E$, which would mean $\theta_0 = 0$ (i.e. the dipole is aligned with the field). In this case, the energy you measure will be positive for $\theta >0$.

Both conventions are equally valid, and it depends on your preference which one you choose, but first one is more popular.